What exactly does the extended Euclidean algorithm compute for polynomials over a commutative ring?
Let $f,g\in A[x]$ with $A$ a commutative ring. IIUC, the extended Euclidean algorithm computes a minimal degree element in the ideal $\langle f,g\rangle\vartriangleleft A[x]$ (alongside the Bézout coefficients). Is this correct?
Assume $\gcd(f,g)\in A[x]$ exists. Is it realized by any such minimal degree element?

I'm only aware of an extended Euclidean algorithm for elements of an Euclidean domain. $A[x]$ is an Euclidean domain iff $A$ is a field.
Regardless, even if there is a more general algorithm that computes a minimal degree element of of $\langle f,g\rangle$, the answer to the second question is no, for the reason that the $\gcd$ may exist without lying in the ideal $\langle f,g\rangle$ (e.g. $f=x,g=y$ for $A=k[y]$).

The algorithm I have in mind over a commutative ring is to row-reduce the Sylvester matrix of $f,g$. (Multiplying one by the leading coefficient of the other to ensure the process can terminate.)
